# Using different quantization modes in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization

TF's [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization#whats_next) on their quantization script appears to only include `--mode=eightbit` (July 24, 2017).

What are each of the modes used for? i.e. as indicated in quantize_graph.py (round, quantize, weights, weights_rounded):

```
flags.DEFINE_string("mode", "round",
                """What transformation to apply (round, quantize,"""
                """ eightbit, weights, or weights_rounded).""")
```

As a complementary question, I tried to trace through the script and noticed that `eightbit` doesn't actually call any of the functions that compute min/max values (ex. quantize_weight_eightbit). So what is mode=eightbit doing exactly?